# Passing a null context to a database helper

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a static function that gets called whenever my background service gets a new location. In this function I want to take to coordinates passed in and save them in my database. Can I pass 'null' as the context to create an instance of the database helper or is there a better way to do this. Thanks.

```
public static void locationHasChanged() {
    final wd_DatabaseHelper helper = new wd_DatabaseHelper(null, "myDB.db", null, 1);
}
```

Comment: It depends what `wd_DatabaseHelper` extends and what it does with the `Context` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Usually your Database helper extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and the context will be used to call the `openOrCreateDatabase()` or the `getDatabasePath()`. I can't say for sure without seeing the code of wd_DatabaseHelper but having a null context is never a good idea. See for your self ... [Source of SQLiteOpenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java)

Answer (score 0):

since an android Service is a context you can pass "this of the service" into your method

```
public class MyLocationHelper {
public static void locationHasChanged(Context context) {
    final wd_DatabaseHelper helper = new wd_DatabaseHelper(context, "myDB.db", null, 1);
    ....
}
}

public class MyService extends Service {

    private void onLocationHasChanged()
    {
        MyLocationHelper.locationHasChanged(this);
    }
}
```